# Change GKE cluster name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there a way to change the cluster name of a GKE cluster?

I know that it is not possible with kubeadm clusters and would need redeployment with the desired name. Is that true in case of GKE clusters as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think not but it's a reasonable request and it's unclear why renaming resources isn't possible generally (?) with Google Cloud Platform resources.

> The only reason I can envisage is that resources become uniquely identified by fully-qualified names that include the name. If these names are referenced in other resources, it could be difficult to rename all occurrences.

The challenge is that most GCP methods specify the resource upon which the method is to be applied using some combination of the project, location and the resource name, e.g. [projects.locations.clusters](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest#rest-resource:-v1beta1.projects.locations.clusters) methods are mostly all:

> The name (project, location, cluster) of the cluster to update. Specified in the format projects/*/locations/*/clusters/*.

So there would need to be a separate move|rename method. Someone raised this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146413933) before but it has languished without much love. If you'd like to promote it, you may wish to (star) it.

Comment: Thank you, I have starred it, let's see if that makes any changes.